# Dynamic programming approach or a case that fails the greedy

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have a string of length `1 <= |S| <= 100` and `K (1 <= K <= 10)`

This string contains `digits < K` and question marks. I want to replace these question marks with `digits < K`, no two neighboring digits being equal. The string is circular so it can't be like this: `1?1` or `11?`.

The resulting string must be lexicographically the smallest one.

Example input and output

```
input:
K = 4
string = ?????

output:
01012
```

I've tried a greedy approach but it fails for some unknown testcases. I think it needs a dp approach but couldn't figure out the states, and a pure recursion code won't fit in time.

Any help for the dp approach, or tricky test cases that fail the greedy?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know it fails if you don't know the test cases it fails on?

Comment: Wouldn't generating a test case that "fails the greedy" require know ing which greedy algorithm is being used?

Comment: @ScottHunter it gives Wrong answer when submitting on online judge and i have implemented my greedy solution efficiently, so i am sure it needs a dp approach

Comment: my greedy approach is to iterate from left to right and put the minimum valid k at each question mark index

Comment: @n.m. if you are at index 0 then your neighbors will be ((LENGTH(S) - 1), 1)

Comment: `K = 2, ???0??` fails the greedy approach. Try to understand why.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nice example. However there still is a greedy approach, which will actually be able to solve this. It's just not the one mentioned above. There is no DP needed to solve this.

Comment: @LiKao I haven't taken the time to prove it, but that's what I thought. When analysing the example, it should become clear how to modify the algorithm, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I haven't proven it either, but I am pretty confident that it should work. Matroids are fearsome beasts so I avoid proving a Matroid at this time of the evening.

Comment: This question is from a running contest http://www.codechef.com/JUNE12/problems/CAKEDOOM. I believe it is unethical to ask such queries in a running contest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a digit at one end of string, the greedy algorithm will give you the right answer.

If your string starts and ends with a question mark, you have 2 possibilites for the first character (0 or 1), run the greedy algorithm on both cases and take the best.

**Wrong answer as pointed out by Likao:**

The greedy works but you must start with the first question mark which is just after a known digit.

Comment: Uhm, not quite. I think to minimize it, one needs to take the first question mark in front of (and not after) the known digit. But the principle is the same.

Comment: Exactly right. Greedy will do the work, but you must "rotate" your string so that you start with fixed boundary condition

Answer (score 0):

Its simple backtracking imo.Why complicating it with greedy or dynamic.

Comment: No, sure it will fail in time. with worst case string of length 100 full of '?'